# Click is happening automatically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have written below javascript whose function is to `trigger click` of another button(Skip and Continue) on the click of first button (Continue).

`'button.yelbtn'` is the `button class of "Continue"` button.

`'button.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn'` is the `button` class of "Skip and Continue" button.

```
<script> 
(function()
{
     'use strict';
      var cnt=6000;
      function init() 
      {
          if(typeof jQuery !="undefined")
          {         
            closeOverlay(); 
          }
          else
          {
              cnt=cnt-500;
              if(cnt>500)setTimeout(init,500);
          }
      }


function closeOverlay()
{

    $('button.yelbtn').on('click',function()
    {
        if(window.isDummyClick) 
        {
               $('button.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn').trigger('click');
              $('.flexi-promotion-popup').hide();
        }                
    });             
window.isDummyClick = true;
$('button.yelbtn').trigger('click'); 

}
 init();
})();
</script>
```

This `javascript` is referenced on the html page. When the page is loaded this script runs but `autoclick` of Continue button happens and that triggers the click of `"Skip and Continue"` button. My objective is to trigger the click of `"Skip and Continue"` button only on the manual `click` of `"Continue" button.`

Can someone please check this javascript and check if we can fix this? Thank you in advance.

Want to add more on this if that could help: `Dom manipulation` on html page is done by `React` JS by updating the `Redux` state.

Comment: what you want  ? First of all your description is not specifying your goal ! Do you want the continue button get autoclicked and than want user to click on skip and continue manually ?

Comment: Hi @satyampathak I want to trigger the click of "Skip and Continue" button  on the manual click of "Continue" button. Right now with my script, autoclick of Continue button is happening and thus "Skip and Conitnue" button is trigerring.I do not want the autoclick of Continue button.

Comment: Ok @ambika see my answer and check it the goal is fulfilled

Comment: @AmbikaTewari , try remove this statement `$('button.yelbtn').trigger('click'); `

Comment: @satyampathak With your code, "Skip and Continue" button is triggering with the doubleclick of "Continue" button. I want "Skip and Continue" button to trigger on the single click of "Continue" button.

Comment: @AmbikaTewari really ? well i am not sure ! posting codepen link check that out, it is happening on a single click only! If not ?  I guess you need new mouse :D

Answer (score 1):

**Updated as per the requirement**

You just need to attach a click listener to the `skip and continue button` and `trigger` it when you `click` the `continue button`.

[CodePen link to cross check :)](https://codepen.io/satyamqainfotech/pen/KBoORx?editors=1010)

See the snippet below !

```js
(function()
{
     'use strict';
      var cnt=6000;
      function init() 
      {
          if(typeof jQuery !="undefined")
          {         
            closeOverlay(); 
          }
          else
          {
              cnt=cnt-500;
              if(cnt>500)setTimeout(init,500);
          }
      }


function closeOverlay()
{
    $('.yelbtn').on('click',function()
    {
        if(window.isDummyClick) 
        {
          $('.skip-cnt-btn').trigger('click') // trigger skip and continue button
        }                
    });             
window.isDummyClick = true;
}
 init();
$('.skip-cnt-btn').on('click', function(){
alert('i am skip and continue button and got triggered on click of continue button')}); // attach click to skip and continue button
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class= "yelbtn">continue</button>
<button class = "skip-cnt-btn"> skip and continue</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want trigger the click of "Skip and Continue" button only on the manual click of "Continue" button.

you should remove this statement:

```
$('button.yelbtn').trigger('click');
```

Otherwise this expression will trigger the click of "Skip and Continue" button when first run `closeOverlay`.

and if you don't want click "Skip and Continue" button trigger itself, do some control like below:

```js
function clickSkip() {
    if (window.isDummyClick) {
        console.log('trigger');
        window.isDummyClick = false
    }
}
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var cnt = 6000;

    function init() {
        if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
            closeOverlay();
        } else {
            cnt = cnt - 500;
            if (cnt > 500) setTimeout(init, 500);
        }
    }

    function closeOverlay() {
        $('.yelbtn').on('click', function() {
            window.isDummyClick = true;
            $('.skip-cnt-btn').trigger('click');
            $('.flexi-promotion-popup').hide();
        });
        // $('button.yelbtn').trigger('click');
    }

    init();
})();
```

```html
 
<button class='yelbtn'>Continue</button>
<button class='skip-cnt-btn' onclick="clickSkip()">Skip and Continue</button>
<button class='flexi-promotion-popup'>indigo</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Ian Zhong , if I remove the statement  $('button.yelbtn').trigger('click'); 
auto click of Continue button stops happening however Skip and Continue button is trigerring with the re-click (double click) of Continue button

Comment: @AmbikaTewari, I'm confused, Skip and Continue button is triggering when Continue button is manual clicked, Isn't this you want?

Comment: Btw, double click trigger nothing in this case.